# What is the fastest way to transfer data from azure blob storage to google cloud storage?

Tags: azure, google-cloud-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm currently trying to transfer my data from azure blob storage to google cloud storage.
I've tried using azcopy but it didn't work, so I need a suggestion from you guys.
Thank you.

Comment: You may refer previous so thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41157327/transfer-file-from-azure-blob-storage-to-google-cloud-storage-programmatically?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exporting data from Google Cloud Storage to Amazon S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39329580/exporting-data-from-google-cloud-storage-to-amazon-s3)