# Does gsutil support copying files from Azure Storage?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, azure-storage, gsutil

gsutil supports copying files from S3 to GCS like mentioned in this [blog](https://justrocketscience.com/post/copy-s3-gcs). Does gsutil tool also supports copying files from Azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gsutil supports transfers from [Amazon](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/create-manage-transfer-console#configure) only, for the time being.

However, it is possible to use third party software like [Rclone](https://rclone.org/) that is available for many platforms. You can use it to synchronize files and directories.

Also to transfer files from Azure, you can use [Azure Data Factory custom activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41157327/transfer-file-from-azure-blob-storage-to-google-cloud-storage-programmatically?rq=1) like explained in this thread and [Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/v1/data-factory-use-custom-activities).

Comment: This answer is not correct. The reason gsutil supports transfers from Amazon is because gsutil integrates with the S3 API (in addition to the GCS JSON API). gsutil doesn't integrate with the Azure API.

Answer (score 0):

AzCopy v10 (Preview) now supports Amazon Web Services (AWS) S3 as a data source. You can now copy an entire AWS S3 bucket, or even multiple buckets, to Azure Blob Storage using AzCopy. [Move your data from AWS S3 to Azure Storage using AzCopy](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/move-your-data-from-aws-s3-to-azure-storage-using-azcopy/)

If you are really looking for this feature. You may leave your [User Voice here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage). All the feedback you share in this forums will be monitored and reviewed by the Microsoft engineering teams responsible for building Azure

Comment: The OP is trying to copy from Azure to GCS is he not?