# Azure Dev Pipelines Copying files to google cloud storage?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, azure-devops, google-cloud-storage

Part of our deployment requirements is to upload some files to a Google Storage Bucket from hosted Azure DevOps. I am trying to figure out what the best solution for this is or will I have to write a custom task using node to accomplish it?

I did find an existing task (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GlobalFreightSolutionsLtd.copy-files-to-google-buckets), which seems like it would easily meet my needs, but I was unable to get it to work due to this error:

`ResumableUploadError: A resumable upload could not be performed. The directory, C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.config, is not writable`

Any suggestions on a way to do this without needing to write a custom task by just using the command line to install the required modules and software or should I simply dive in and learn how to write a custom task to accomplish this.

Comment: May I know how's the status of this before weekend? Does work around is suitable for you?

Comment: I’ve actually been able to accomplish this by using an inline node script. I’ll post my solution soon.

Answer (score 1):

I am not the one who belong and familiar with GCP, but as the error message you shared. It seems the default issue of `gcs-resumable-upload` node-module. See this [github talking](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/issues/807) and this [one](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/pull/915). This need you contact the  this extension creator to solve.

---

It of course has another ways can make you achieve files copied to `google cloud storage`, without writing a custom task. Since there's no available corresponding gcs cli tool can be used, here it is more complex because you need make use of [Azure Blob storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-introduction).

The working logic of my method is:

1) In Azure devops, add [Azure file copy](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureFileCopyV1/README.md) task into pipeline. Then configure it by referring below format, to copy files into **Azure Blob Storage**:

```
steps:
- task: AzureFileCopy@3
  displayName: 'AzureBlob File Copy'
  inputs:
    SourcePath: WebApi/Dockerfile
    azureSubscription: '{subscription name}'
    Destination: AzureBlob
    storage: {storage account}
    ContainerName: {the container Name}
  enabled: false
```

2) Then you can check this helpful [thread solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56686842/11508165) to get guide on how to copy files from `Azure Blob Storage` to `Google Cloud Storage` directly.

Just hope this method would more convenient than writing a custom task for you:-)